# DAX subquery same table with filter

Tags: sql-server, dax

I've the following SQL which I try to convert to DAX:

```
SELECT code, text,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM table1 A
      WHERE created <= Convert(DateTime,'2023-06-24 17:00:00')
        AND (col1 is null or col1 > Convert(DateTime,'2023-06-24 17:00:00'))
        AND (col2 is null or col2 > Convert(DateTime,'2023-06-24 17:00:00'))
    AND A.code = table2.code
    AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
       FROM table1 B
     WHERE B.created <= Convert(DateTime,'2023-07-24 17:00:00')
       AND (B.col1 is null or B.col1 > Convert(DateTime,'2023-07-24 17:00:00'))
       AND (B.col2 is null or B.col2 > Convert(DateTime,'2023-07-24 17:00:00'))
       AND A.col3 = B.col3
        )
    ) AS 'New'
    FROM table2
ORDER BY table2.created
```

I want to get a table with three columns: table2[code], table2[text], "New" and here is my DAX code:

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( table2[code], table2[text], "New",
 CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(table1), FILTER( table1, table1[created] <= DATE(2023, 6, 24, 17, 0, 0)
 && (ISBLANK(table1[col1]) || table1[col1] > DATE(2023, 6, 24, 17, 0, 0)) 
 && (ISBLANK(table1[col2]) || table1[col2] > DATE(2023, 6, 24, 17, 0, 0))
 && table1[code] = RELATED(table2[code] )
 && ISEMPTY( FILTER( table1, table1[created] <= DATE(2023, 7, 24, 17, 0, 0))
 && (ISBLANK(table1[col1]) || table1[col1] > DATE(2023, 7, 24, 17, 0, 0)) 
 && (ISBLANK(table1[col2]) || table1[col2] > DATE(2023, 7, 24, 17, 0, 0)) 
 && table1[col3] = table1[col3] ) )
) ) ORDER BY table2.created
 ORDER BY table2[created]
```

But I don't know how to subquery the same table in DAX. Any suggestion how to complete the dax code above?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide the model, I am assuming that you are aware in DAX nested queries are handled somewhat differently compared to SQL.

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    table2[code],
    table2[text],
    "New", 
    VAR BaseDateJune = DATETIME(2023, 6, 24, 17, 0, 0)
    VAR BaseDateJuly = DATETIME(2023, 7, 24, 17, 0, 0)
    RETURN CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(table1),
        FILTER(
            table1,
            table1[created] <= BaseDateJune &&
            (ISBLANK(table1[col1]) || table1[col1] > BaseDateJune) && 
            (ISBLANK(table1[col2]) || table1[col2] > BaseDateJune) &&
            NOT(
                CALCULATE(
                    COUNTROWS(table1),
                    FILTER(
                        table1,
                        table1[created] <= BaseDateJuly &&
                        (ISBLANK(table1[col1]) || table1[col1] > BaseDateJuly) && 
                        (ISBLANK(table1[col2]) || table1[col2] > BaseDateJuly) && 
                        table1[col3] = EARLIER(table1[col3])
                    )
                ) > 0
            )
        )
    )
)
```